# Scanners and multiple if statements

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get a Scanner to read through each line of data and only print out the lines that contain the word "model" followed by a year within the boundaries I set. I am not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this, but I made one Scanner  for the whole set of data and then within that I declared another one that reads each line. I then tried to set it to look for a String comprised of the word "model" plus the year if the line contains the right year. Since tokens in Scanners are divided by spaces, I thought the correct way to do it would to declare a different String, tokenToken, that combines the first token with a space and the year, if such a combination exists.

Currently when I run it, it just runs forever, but never completes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inStream = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (inStream.hasNext()) {

        String line = inStream.nextLine();
        Scanner lineStream = new Scanner(line);

        while (lineStream.hasNext()) {
            String token = lineStream.next();
            if (token.matches("model") && lineStream.hasNextInt()) {
                int year= lineStream.nextInt();
                if ((year>= 1976) && (year <= 2013)) {
                    String tokenToken = (token + " " + year);

                    if (lineStream.hasNext(tokenToken)) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    } else {
                    }

                }


            }
        }
        lineStream.close();

    }
    inStream.close();
}
```

Comment: *"it just runs forever, not compiling"* So does it compile or not?

Comment: I mean when data is entered nothing happens.

Comment: @user2781450 Would you mind get the line with scanner into a string and split that string into a a string array then analyze(loop through) that array instead, to find the "model"+" "+"year(year>= 1976) && (year <= 2013)" you are looking for. If you can consider that let us know it is easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

To start of, where do you get int from ??

```
lineStream.hasNextInt()
```

?? all i can see everywhere are Strings.

Edit:
I think this is what you are looking for in terms of splitting the string and processing it correctly.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = input.nextLine();

    String[] parts = name.split(" ");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];

    int year = Integer.parseInt(part2);      
    if(part1.contains("model")){            
        if((year >= 1976) && (year <= 2013)){
            System.out.println(name);
        }else{
            System.out.println("wtf?");
        }
    }
}
```

Now what you have to do is just put it into a loop of desired time/size whatever is that you wish